# Red potatoes-partial cooking, freezing to bake at a later date

Tags: storage-method, kitchen-safety

I am trying to par cook shredded red potatoes with the skins on and then freeze them until baking at a later date. My concern is keeping the potatoes from turning brown until cooked.

Answer (score 1):

They're not going to brown in the freezer. All you have to do is make sure they're not browned before you put them in, and that you cook them reasonably promptly when you take them out.

So if you're shredding a lot, hold them in water til you're ready to cook them. After cooking, rinse to cool them, drain them well and pat them dry before freezing.

Comment: That's a great answer. A spritz of lemon juice will also slow oxidation quite a bit.